# Multiple filters, aggregation and grouping in the same column

Tags: sql-server, filtering, grouping

I want to get the average Price per Unit per City and per Year from the following table.

```
   Date         City     Units  Price
   10/23/2018   Leon       1    1088
   2/27/2018    NewYork    1    1312
   4/19/2017    Texas      3    3909
   4/19/2017    London     1    1303
   4/19/2019    NewYork    3    3909
   2/12/2018    Leon       1    1251
   4/7/2017     Leon       3    3510
   3/20/2019    London     1    1650
   12/18/2017   Texas      1    1358
   2/18/2019    Leon       1    1088
   7/3/2017     NewYork    2    2782
   8/8/2019     Texas      1    830
   4/5/2018     London     2    3739
   1/29/2018    Londres    1    1169
   8/9/2019     Texas      1    1130
```

To get AvgPrice number of units should be considered, then it should be grouped by year and shown per each City as follows:

```
 Year   City       AvgPrice
 2017   Leon       1170
 2017   London     1303
 2017   New York   1391
 2017   Texas      1330.5
 2018   London     1519.25
 2018   New York   1312
 2018   Leon       1169.5
 2019   Leon       1088
 2019   London     1650
 2019   New York   1303
 2019   Texas      1390
```

I have tried grouping per city but it gets complicated per year. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please show us what you tried, and explain why it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Also, those dates look suspicious. You aren't storing them as a `varchar` are you?

Comment: Nope, dates are date type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(Date), City, SUM(1.0 * Units * price) / SUM(1.0 * Units) AS AvPrice
        GROUP BY Year(Date), City
```

so if you sold 2 at $2 and 1 at $5, it will make the average price 9 divided by 3, is $3 - otherwise single sales would be weighted more heavily per unit than multiple sales - that's the reason for SUM(units * price)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following should work:

```
SELECT
    YEAR([Date]) [Year]
    , City
    , CAST(CAST(SUM(Price) AS decimal(19, 2)) / SUM(Units) AS decimal(19, 2)) AverageUnitPrice
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY
    YEAR([Date])
    , City
```

(To get your exact output visually, you could cast as `float` rather than `decimal(19, 2)` (the outer `CAST` would also not be necessary).)